# Display Errors in an unordered list format in PHP

Tags: php, listitem

I want to display all the errors stored in $error in an unordered list format. The following is the code that will display the errors.

```
<?php
     if (!empty($error)) {
         echo '<p class="error"><strong>Your message was NOT sent<br/> The following error(s) occurred:</strong><br/>'. '<li>' . $error . '</li>' . '</p>';
     } elseif (!empty($success)) {
         echo $success;
       }
?>
```

The problem is that the above code only display the first error in a list but rest of them are just showing in a separate line with no list format. All the errors are stored in the following format:

```
$error .= "You didn't type in your name. <br />";
```

I tried removing br tags but that didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if (!empty($error)) {
        $errors = explode('<br />', $error);
        echo '
<p class="error"><strong>Your message was NOT sent<br/>The following error(s) occurred:</strong></p>
<ul>
';
        foreach($errors as $error){
             echo "<li>$error</li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    } elseif (!empty($success)) {
        echo $success;

    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes.. This one works nicely for me... :)
Can you explain how this explode functions works in this case??

Comment: @TBI it just splits your text at the line breaks (and removes them) and puts each piece into a simple zero indexed array. Opposite of the `implode` command. Both are very useful, along with `extract`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<li>` for each error instead if using     `<br/>` tag, The output of PHP should like this,

```
<ul>
    <li>Error1</li>
    <li>Error2</li>
    <li>Error3</li>
</ul>
```

So have PHP code like this,

```
$error .= "<li>You didn't type in your name. </li>";
$error .= "<li>Error2. </li>";
$error .= "<li>Error3 </li>";


echo '<p class="error"><strong>Your message was NOT sent<br/> The following error(s) occurred:</strong><br/>'. '<ul>' . $error . '</ul>' . '</p>';
```

Comment: I did thought of this before but it would be time consuming if I have too many errors to display. Hence, I have choose the answer provided by keyboardSmasher.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$error` is an array (seems so).

```
if (!empty($error)) {
    foreach ($error as $e) {
        printf("<li>%s</li>\n", $e);
    }
}

// or just
print "<li>". join("</li>\n<li>", $error). "</li>";

// extra: collecting errors
if (trim($_POST["first_name"]) == "") {
    $error[] = "You didn't type in your first name.";
}
if (trim($_POST["last_name"]) == "") {
    $error[] = "You didn't type in your last name.";
}
...
```